# Change the existing Hadoop Cluster Name

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I need to change the "cluster name" of an existing production Hadoop cluster..
I searched a lot on google..but could not find a way...anyone knows how to rename the cluster name?

I am using Hortonworks HDP2.1 distro of Hadoop.

Comment: You better ask this question in Hortonworks forum. hortonworks.com/community/forums/

Comment: what name are you talking about? the FQDN of the NameNode? the Hostname? In either case the best way is to start over and migrate whatever data you have into the new cluster.

Comment: @apesa - probably the Ambari cluster name

Comment: I was referring to Hadoop cluster name which needs to be given during cluster installation. This feature was not available in Ambari 1.5 but Ambari 1.7+ support this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the cluster name in Ambari.

You can't yet - [AMBARI-4671](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/AMBARI-4671)

Answer (score 0):

On Ambari 2.0:

Click on your username in the top right hand corner and go to Manager Ambari. You can see your current cluster name in the top left hand corner with a little edit icon next to it, click that and you can rename the cluster.

Be warned though as this will effect some configuration; for example, if you are using Ranger for security then this will create a fresh repo for each service and effectively compromise your security permissions.